# Unable to size nav to 100% height correctly

Tags: css, magento, height

I'm trying to make my magento left navigation the same height as the main container.

I've done tons of research and can't find a solution that works for me. I have

- Set all parent div's to 100%, but I end up with a broken theme and can't figure out why.
- Set html, body, wrapper, main...to 100% and can get the nav to stretch correctly, but it pushes my footer very far down.
- Tried following the instructions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198604/left-navigation-wont-expand-to-100-magento) and can't get it to work for me either, but it brought up some questions.

How this person was able to achieve this without setting html to 100%? and body to 100% which i thought was required.

Some help and explanation would be very appreciated. site is [www.theimagecollective.com](http://theimagecollective.com)

Answer (score 0):

I am curious

1. are you just looking to put the subscribe block at the bottom?
2. evenly distribute the navigation from top to bottom of the main
   container?

the left container is at 100% of what is being displayed in that container. Even if you expanded to the same px height of the main container it would look the same unless you do something with the css of the blocks that are in the left container.

Comment: well I'm going to be doing some formatting to the site. I'm changing the bg of the entire content area to white but I want the nav to go all the way to the bottom of every page filled with a gray color. Currently when I change the content area to white, the nav gray ends just under the subscribe block instead of going all the way down.

Comment: the answer was to extend the nav from top to bottom of main container

Comment: on line 634 of your CSS you can change the height to say 800px and add the backgound-color:#000 or what ever.. the background image you have on there is blocking the color change.. So using Chrome i was able to make those changes, hide your background image and it showed the black background to the 800px i used for testing.

Comment: understood. But i cant use a fixed height because on the product pages the heights can vary. That's why i'm trying to get it to use 100%. I was only using the bg image in trying to replicate the other posts fix.

Comment: you could always use a position:fixed; on your .col-left with the static height of 800, but probably the easiest is with the image in the .main